# Comparing Age variables within a range

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two age variables: "age" is from the survey firm's data, "agesurvey" is an age question I asked in the survey. I want to compare them as a data check. However, often the age is +/- one year. How can I code this in r?

```r
age <- c(18, 50, 41, 79)
agesurvey <- c(19, 50, 40, 79)
```

My draft

```r
check <- df %>% mutate ("Agree" = ifelse(age == agesurvey, "Correct", "Incorrect"))
table(check$Agree)
```

Comment: Next time, please provide more information on the output or error when you run your  "draft". In your example, the two variables are not in the same data.frame. However, did you try to remove the quotes around `Agree` within `mutate()` when you run your draft on your data?

Comment: I had no issues at all with the equation; it worked perfectly. However my goal was different. Both variables are in the same dataframe, I will reflect that next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `abs(a - b) <= threshold`.

```r
ifelse(abs(age - agesurvey) <= 1, "Correct", "Incorrect")

# [1] "Correct" "Correct" "Correct" "Correct"
```